# Change Redirect Path

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5.3

So I am building this web application in laravel framework (version 5.3) and I want to change the redirect path whenever user fails login, So far I've tried this piece of code in my LoginController.php

```
protected $loginPath = "/my-given-path";
```

---

But it just doesn't seem to work, So I tried inspecting this AuthenticatesUsers trait and got to this file and then to RedirectUsers trait and there no such function revolving around `$loginPath` exists, but `$redirectTo` exists.

---

Alright so I came back to AuthenticatesUsers trait and inspected couple of functions to see this :-

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->credentials($request);

    if ($this->guard()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if (! $lockedOut) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

hence I need to inspect this `sendFailedLoginResponse()' function and so here it goes :-

```
 protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
        ]);
}
```

So now I tried changing `redirect()->back()...` to `redirect('/my-given-path')...` but still no luck.

---

I have been trying to solve this problem for the whole day and can't come up with solution and the one's asked before aren't of laravel 5.3 version.
hence, I'd be glad if someone could tell what's going on and where I am being wrong?

Comment: i guess it's redirect back to the same url because of the validation not because of auth failed

Comment: Oh, yeah I think you are correct! So is there any way to handle the path to which it will be redirected in case if validation fails?

Comment: add this function to loginController 
`protected function getRedirectUrl()
    {
        return 'path';
    }`

Comment: Nope,it still redirects back to the same page.

Comment: did you change the sendFailedLoginResponse function

Comment: No, i didn't. (I mean I tried changing but nothing happened so i reverted it to it's original state as show above in the code)

Comment: change both of them to the path that you want

Comment: I think there's some change in 5.3 version, check out this thread, [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-auth-login-path-not-redirecting-to-correct-path-on-incorrect-credentials)

Comment: and nope, still not working. (redirectTo is working but loginPath nope,)

Comment: Hey ABDEL, it worked finally! and seems i was doing something wrong BUT `$loginPath` is no longer supported as I have to change that `redirect()->back()...` to `redirect('/my-given-url')...` in AuthenticatesUser.php trait file.

Comment: great it works , yeah it's not , but if you want to change loginview override the showLoginForm method

Comment: oh thanks, but I didn't want to change it, still cheers for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, So I found the solution, Actually I think I was doing something wrong when changing `redirect()->back()...` to `redirect('/my-given-url')...` in my AuthenticatesUsers.php file under function `sendFailedLoginResponse()`.

---

But `$loginPath` is no longer working and no such function exists in RedirectUsers trait, when $redirectTo exists.
So I have to manually hardcode my desired path in the function of AuthenticatesUsers trait.